# How to display a property value based on another property value of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON that contains objects where each has "href" and "message" properties. If the URL matches the href, the corresponding message should appear in the console log. So if the URL has "apples" in it, it should console log the word "Yes!"

This is what I have so far...

```js
var banner = [
        {
            'href': 'apples',
            'message': 'yes!'
        },
        {
            'href': 'oranges',
            'message': 'no!'
        },
        {
            'href': 'grapes',
            'message': 'maybe!'
        },
    ];

    if (window.location.href.indexOf(banner.name)) {
      console.log(banner.message);
    }
```

Comment: What is the desired result for above snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out data like this

```
var banner = [
        {
            'href': 'apples',
            'message': 'yes!'
        },
        {
            'href': 'oranges',
            'message': 'no!'
        },
        {
            'href': 'grapes',
            'message': 'maybe!'
        },
    ];

function findFromBannerData(query) {
    filterData = banner.filter(item => {
      if (item.href === query) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    return filterData;
}
console.log(findFromBannerData('oranges'));
```

If the returned value from function is not empty array then it has the value you need means `Yes!`

****Edited Answer :****

```
if (window.location.href && banner) {
    let result = banner.find(item => window.location.href.includes(item.href))
    if (result) {
        console.log(result.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why to use `filter` when you have `find`. The `filter` won't stop the search if the element is found but `find` would.

Comment: @decpk I have added both answers now

Comment: Not sure if I understand your code correctly but I'm trying to make this dynamic. So if the user is in a page where the URL in the address bar contains the word "apples" then it should console log as "Yes!", if it contains "oranges" then "No!" and if it contains "grapes" then "Maybe!" Results (message) should be based on its corresponding href property.

Comment: @shoegazer changes made to the post

Comment: I'm getting an error but your code is heading in the right direction because your console log is dynamic.

Comment: @shoegazer You can apply for undefined check on `window.location.href` and `banner` and `result` to be more error proof.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `href` with any `string`. Just [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the element if the `href` exist in any of the objects in the `banner` object.

```
const href = window.location.href;
```

or

```
const result = banner.find((o) => window.location.href.includes(o.href));
```

```js
var banner = [{
    href: "apples",
    message: "yes!",
  },
  {
    href: "oranges",
    message: "no!",
  },
  {
    href: "grapes",
    message: "maybe!",
  },
];

const href = "www.grapes.com";

const result = banner.find((o) => href.includes(o.href));
if (result) {
  console.log("Yes")
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your code correctly but I'm trying to make this dynamic. So if the user is in a page where the URL in the address bar contains the word "apples" then it should console log as "Yes!", if it contains "oranges" then "No!" and if it contains "grapes" then "Maybe!" Results (message) should be based on its corresponding href property.

Comment: Please add what is your desired result, so that I can help you...

Comment: I'm not trying to pick any of the objects, it should be picked dynamically based on user's window.location.href. If I am understanding your code correctly, you picked "grapes" to console log a result based on grapes.

Comment: then just replace `href` with `window.location.href` and code works fine and dynamically

Comment: @shoegazer answer updated. I took `grapes` as an example that's why I've explained above that `You can replace href with any string`

Comment: I removed the const and replaced the "yes" in console.log with result.message to make it dynamic and it worked. thanks!